# Linq query question based on order dates

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq and struggling to create a query. The tables are 'Customers' table and 'Orders' table with a one-to-many relationship.

I have a funcion where I want to return a list of customers.

```
enum CustomerStatus
{
    one,
    two,
    three
}

public List<Customer> GetCustomerByStatus(enum customerStatus)
{
   ...
}
```

so if I call the above function as `GetCustomerBystatus(one)`I want a list of 
customers, whose most recent order has a order date < today.

If I call the above function as `GetCustomerBystatus(two)`I want a list of 
customers, whose most recent order has a order date = today.

If I call the above function as `GetCustomerBystatus(one)`I want a list of 
customers, whose most recent order has a order date > today.

What is the best way to write the linq statements?

I hope that makes sense. thank you.

Comment: I don't really see a question here...

Comment: @ck, the question is clear to me, why anyone would want to code it that way is less clear.

Comment: @fear: the edit added an actual question, before that there wasn't one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian is correct.  Here is a sample.

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerByStatus(CustomerStatus customerStatus)
    {
        var query = from customer in this.Customers
                        select customer;

        switch (customerStatus)
        {
            case CustomerStatus.one:
                query = query.Where(customer => customer...);
                break;
            case CustomerStatus.two:
                query = query.Where(customer => customer...);
                break;
            case CustomerStatus.three:
                query = query.Where(customer => customer...);
                break;
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I tried something like this but I don't think I have done it right:  customers = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.Orderdate > DateTime.Now.Date)).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Build your query as you normally would, without any of the filtering.

Then in a switch block you can apply different where clauses based on what enum value is passed into the method.

Comment: Also, since you're returning a list, you should call `ToList()` on the query **after** the switch block, when the query is fully composed.

Comment: what is the best way to write the linq query?